# what does it mean when firebug throws an error message "(59 out of range 26)"

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, firebug

I have a jquery tab plugin I made myself, and i'm using it on my main page, then loading in tab content via ajax within the plugin.

In the page being loaded I have the same plugin being initialized as another instance.

```
page 1
$("#index").tabs();

page2
$("#theme").tabs();
```

page1 tab works, page 2 tabs work, but when I load in page2 then FireBug gives me this error

```
tab_id is not defined
    (59 out of range 26)
```

Comment: what did you put in the `selector`?

Comment: i edited my post to show my selectors

Comment: Not enough information.  Is this a Firefox plugin or a Firebug plugin?   Where is the code that references `tab_id`?  Link(s) to full code is best.

Comment: Its a jquery plugin I made, should probably be more specific

Comment: I have a problem like this could you bring us your answer?

Comment: Did anyone every figureout what causes the (# out of range #) message?

Comment: it was just an error in the logic of the plug-in. I'm not 100% sure what it means but when it reached a specific line in the javascript it ran into an error that forced the entire script to stop. Firebug I guess pics up the error call and translates it into its own error message

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Nevermind, I had an error in my logic for my plugin that won't let me use more than one instance.

Comment: Show the error and the solution!  It might help someone else out with a similar problem.

Comment: I'll come back to this post and leave a detailed post on what I did when I finish fine tuning my plug-in

Comment: ... which means you might have finished by now! :-)

Comment: I guess that if you have programing logic error which would make the plugin run in general Firebug doesn't like it and throws out that error. The problem was trivial as using a reserved keyword as a variable.